# Nested views in marionette.js when creating a table

Tags: javascript, listview, backbone.js, html-table, marionette

I have two collections: "collection" and "collection2". I can't figure out how to render both of these collections into the table, but keep them in separate views. Example:

row1: Group 1,

row2: first collection object

row3.. second collection object ....

row 4 Group 2,

row 5 first collection2 object

row 6 second collection2 object ....

Please Help

## JS

```
 (function() {

            // Here's the list of objects that we will be displaying
            var a = JSON.parse('{"type":"report","limit":20,"offset":0,"data":[{"group":"platform","detail":[{"reason":"Invalid Issuer","errorcode":"123456","total":"1","realtotal":"1","nonrecurring":"1","recurring":"0"},{"reason":"Declined","errorcode":"111111","total":"1","realtotal":"1","nonrecurring":"1","recurring":"0"},{"reason":"Insufficient funds","errorcode":"52252","total":"1","realtotal":"1","nonrecurring":"1","recurring":"0"}]},{"group":"gateway","detail":[{"reason":"Transaction timed out","errorcode":"52525","total":"7","realtotal":"3","nonrecurring":"7","recurring":"0"},{"reason":"Error","errorcode":"623","total":"7","realtotal":"3","nonrecurring":"7","recurring":"0"}]}],"page":"1"}');

            var model = new Backbone.Model(a);

            var collection = model;

            var data = collection.get('data');

            var collection = new Backbone.Collection(data[0].detail);
            var collection2 = new Backbone.Collection(data[1].detail);


            var ItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
                className: 'item-view',
                tagName: 'tr',
                template: '#template-color-item',
            });

            var TableView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
                template: '#template-table',
                className: 'table-view',
                tagName: 'table',

                itemViewContainer: 'tbody',
                itemView: ItemView
            });


            var table = new TableView({
                el: '.list',
                collection: collection
            });

            table.render();

          })();
```

## HTML

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>

              <head>
                <title>Superheroes and villains</title>

                <script src="./assets/javascripts/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
                <script src="./assets/javascripts/vendor/json2.js"></script>
                <script src="./assets/javascripts/vendor/underscore.js"></script>
                <script src="./assets/javascripts/vendor/backbone.js"></script>
                <script src="./assets/javascripts/vendor/backbone.marionette.js"></script>
                <script src="./assets/javascripts/vendor/bootstrap.js"></script>

                <link href="./assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


              </head>
              <body>
                <main>

                  <h1>Table</h1>
                  <p>
                    Simple Table rendered with a composite view.
                  </p>

                  <h1>Example</h1>

                  <div class="list"></div>
                </main>


                <script type='text/template' id='template-table'>
                    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <td>header 1</td>
                            <td>header 2</td>
                            <td>header 3</td>
                            <td>header 4</td>
                            <td>header 5</td>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </script>
                <script type='text/template' id='template-color-item'>
                    <td><%= reason %></td>
                    <td><%= errorcode %> </td>
                    <td><%= nonrecurring %></td>
                    <td><%= realtotal %></td>
                    <td><%= recurring %></td>
                </script>

                <script src="./assets/javascripts/application.js"></script>
                <div class="table"></div>
              </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Quick View: https://jsfiddle.net/gxk2n3wd/1/

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason these collections need to be put in the same table but kept in separate views?

If not, it would be straightforward to render all the detail models by concatenating your details arrays:

```
var detailsArrays = a.data.map(function(d) { return d.detail });
var details = _.flatten(detailsArrays); // put all details objects into one array
var collection = new Backbone.Collection(details);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dkrg80yd/